# What is right table design and proper searching queries for my database?

Tags: database, database-design

I try to design mysql tables for following purpose. The site is about any topics and items that belongs to one or several topics - for example lets take topic "Batman". For this, there are items belonging to several categories - *movies*, *books*, *video games* and *cars*(Batmobil). Number of categories is 10-20. My idea is to make these tables:

```
Topic
-------
id
name

Item
-------
id
name
category_id
decscription and some other common columns

Movie (and other categories, like Car, VideoGame, Book,...)
-------
id
item_id 
specific columns for each category

Item_Topic (and other tables like Item_Category, Item_Movie, Item_Car, Item_Videogame, Item_Person...)
-------
item_id
topic_id (movie_id, car_id, person_id, ...)

Person
-------
item_id
name
role
```

So far, I think this is good solution (or am I wrong?)

But my two problems are following:

1. Movie's actors and book's authors in my table design aren't considered as items. For actors and writers there is a table *Person* and *Item-Person*  table for connecting items with persons. But what if a topic would be "Stephen King"? How should I search for Stephen King's books and movies that he wrote scenaries for? Only approach that came on my mind is changing table design and consider persons as items too. Is it good idea?  What is table design solution of this problem? And could you please advise me, how should general query for matching topic and items using proper table design look like?
2. I would like to show all items with detail informations (stored in *Movie*, *Book*, *VideoGame*,...) belonging to one topic on one page - what is the best query I can use?

Thank you very much for any answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me comment on this part of your design:

```
Movie (and other categories, like Car, VideoGame, Book,...)
-------
item_id 
specific columns for each category
```

This is usually not the best approach when using the relational model. If possible, it's better to have a `Category` table with records for `Movie`, `Car`, `VideoGame`, `Book`, etc. That way it's easier to add new categories as neeeded.

If the item data varies widely based on category, there are techniques to handle that, but it's not pretty (commonly a table of item attributes and then your item table is a mapping table of attributes to values).

### Update

Thanks to @RichardCZ for reminding me the attribute mapping approach is called [EAV, Entity–attribute–value, model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Comment: I edited IDs and Category table, I used similar method (array with ID => CategoryName instead of Category table), but this one is probably better. In the 2nd part of your answer, are you talking about something like EAV model? I thought for my case (several categories with strictly defined "columns", adding/editing categories will be rare), several tables are OK. Thank you

Comment: Yes, EAV model. Added Wikipedia link to my answer. Thanks.